# Unable to pull image inside twig file

Tags: views, theming, 9

I am trying to show image via view twig file and below is my lin eof code:

```
<img width="220" height="112" src="{{ file_url(content.field_thumbnail_new[key]['#item'].entity.uri.value )}}" alt="{{ item.alt }}" />
```

When inspecting, I see the below:

[image]

any help on how this can be fixed pls?! I am using D9.

Comment: Why is this not rendered normally?

Comment: I'm not sure. But per the recommended link, I added URL image formatter and added the field as {{ fields.field_thumbnail_new.content }} on my twig. Also I changed the image as "image URI" in view field settings. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak module.

```
<img src="{{ drupal_field('field_thumbnail_new', 'node', node.id, {type: 'image_url', settings: {image_style: 'YOUR_IMAGE_STYLENAME'}}) }}"  />
```

Comment: Thanks! I have added a comment on how i fixedit